# How can I set up a script which copies all modified files and subfolders from folder A to folder B using inotifywait?

Tags: linux, shell, sync

How can I set up a script which copies all modified files and subfolders from folder A to folder B using inotifywait?

I have a folder (A) with lots of files and subfolders.

I want to automatically copy only recently created or modified files and subfolders to folder (B). Older files should not be copied.

I want to use inotifywait for monitoring folder (A). For copying perhaps rsync or a similar tool.

How would the script look like?

Vesa

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-r` option of `inotifywait` to watch all the subdirectories. The `-m` runs infinitely, i.e. doesn't stop watching after the first event.

For `rsync`, use `-R` for relative path names. The slash is needed after the target path, otherwise all files would be copied to the root of the target directory.

```
#! /bin/bash
source=/path/to/A
target=/path/to/B

inotifywait -m -r -e close_write -e moved_to "$source" \
| while read dir event file ; do
    rsync -R "$dir/$file" "$target"/
done
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. It doesn't seem to notice new files or directories.

Comment: Also shouldn't it be moved_from source rather than moved_to source or something like that?

Comment: You want `inotify` to tell you when a new file is *to* source because you then want to copy it to target. When a file is moved *from* source, maybe you want to delete it from target if it exists there?

Comment: Ok I assume you're correct about this. No deleting from target. Anyway, I still couldn't get the script to work.